# loop to normalize range (0,10) in to (0,1)

Tags: python, normalization

What I need is to divide/spread 0 to 1. according to single number which is more than 2.
like number 5 so 0 to 5 will be divided like this

```
0.00  
0.25
0.50
0.75
1.00
```

5 values in a list

and my other question is what to do to get a sequence like this where middle number is 1 and first and last number is 0 , if number is 10.

```
0.00
0.25
0.50
0.75
1.00
1.00
0.75
0.50
0.25
0.00
```

Comment: The upperbound is alwas *exclusive*.

Comment: Instead of `i*(1.0/10)` you can just write `i/10`

Comment: Its because range will start from 0 and end at 9

Comment: Please don't edit your question. Ask a new question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The upper bound of the `range(..)` is ***exclusive*** (meaning it is *not* enumerated), so you need to add *one* step to the `range(..)` function:

```
for i in range(0,11):
     b = i*(1.0/10)
     print b
```

That being said, if you want to create such array, you can use `numpy.arange(..)`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)
array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])
```

This thus allows you to specify floats for the offset, end, and step parameter.

As for your second question, you can `itertools.chain` iterables together, like:

```
from itertools import chain

for i in chain(range(0, 11), range(10, -1, -1)):
    print(i/10.0)
```

Here we thus have *one* `range(..)` that iterates from `0` to `10` (both inclusive), and one that iterates from `10`, to `0` (both inclusive).

Comment: what if maximum number in a list should be not more than 10 ? for second question answer have 22 item in list.

Comment: @AkshatBhargava: but it is not more than 10. As explained the upper bound is *exclusive*. So if you specify `range(m, n)`, then *all* elements `i` are `m <= i < n`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `range(0,11)` to get all the numbers from 0 to 10.

Answer (score 2):

range 0 to 10 will give you numbers from 0 to 9. Here is some practical to explain:

```
>>> list(range(0,10))  
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> list(range(0,11))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

>>> 
>>> list(range(0,1))
[0]

>>>
```